# NHibernate elt field

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate

Does anyone know why NHibernate generates a field named 'elt' of type int for a many to many mapping?
I'm wondering why I need it.
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "elt" field is the foreign key to the element in the many-to-many mapping.  In the join table, you should see two foreign key columns, id (for the parent) and elt (for the element).  You can use different names if you like; these are defaults.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, yes you are right with a little more playing I found that if I 
don't explicitly name the column it defaults to elt.

```
<bag name="equipment" table="tb_room_equipment" lazy="false">
  <key column="roomID"/>
  <many-to-many class="Equipment" column="equipmentID"/>
</bag>
```

Like here, I have now named the column equipmentID; If I don't it will be named elt.

Answer (score 2):

Just recently found out that the **elt** field is created if you have used a **keyword** like **User** or **Role** when using the Mapping By Code. This is just an observation, I have not tried using ` (backtick) to force quotes